# Spring & Hibernate: Why fetch 1 lazy field triggers loading all other lazy fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

In my application, I have a `Staff` entity with a number of lazy-loading fields like this.

```
@Entity(name="CommonStaff")
@Table(name="staff")
@Getter @Setter
public class Staff implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name="nationality", referencedColumnName="code", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Nationality nationality;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name="marital_status", referencedColumnName="code", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private MaritalStatus maritalStatus;

    ...
}
```

When I load a `Staff` record, none of those fields are loaded eagerly as expected. However, when I trigger, for example, `getNationality()`, I'm seeing the framework executing SQL to load `MaritalStatus` as well. I've been trying to find a way to fix this but I couldn't find any useful resource. I'd be very grateful if you could point me in a direction.

Some sample code.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataModuleStaffRepo")
private StaffRepo staffRepo;

@CustomerTransactional
@GetMapping("/profile")
public void testProfile(@RequestParam String userId) {
    Optional<Staff> staff = staffRepo.findByUserId(userId);
    if (staff.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(staff.get().getName());
        System.out.println(staff.get().getNationality().getName());
    }
}
```

Below is what I'm seeing in the console. After the name of the staff was printed, `getNationality()` triggered loading `MaritalStatus` as well.

```
Edgar Rey Tann
2020-04-16 14:29:40,283 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* sequential select
        com.ft.common.db.customer.domain.Staff */ select
            staff_.marital_status as marital19_23_,
            staff_.nationality as nationa22_23_
        from
            staff staff_ 
        where
            staff_.id=?
2020-04-16 14:29:40,283 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [660]
2020-04-16 14:29:40,291 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* load com.ft.common.db.customer.domain.MaritalStatus */ select
        maritalsta0_.id as id1_9_0_,
        maritalsta0_.code as code2_9_0_,
        maritalsta0_.description as descript3_9_0_,
        maritalsta0_.name as name4_9_0_,
        maritalsta0_.order_id as order_id5_9_0_,
        maritalsta0_.short_name as short_na6_9_0_ 
    from
        marital_status maritalsta0_ 
    where
        maritalsta0_.code=?
2020-04-16 14:29:40,291 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [MAR_2]
2020-04-16 14:29:40,298 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL   : 
    /* load com.ft.common.db.customer.domain.Nationality */ select
        nationalit0_.id as id1_16_0_,
        nationalit0_.code as code2_16_0_,
        nationalit0_.description as descript3_16_0_,
        nationalit0_.name as name4_16_0_,
        nationalit0_.order_id as order_id5_16_0_,
        nationalit0_.short_name as short_na6_16_0_ 
    from
        nationality nationalit0_ 
    where
        nationalit0_.code=?
2020-04-16 14:29:40,298 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-2] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder   : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [NAT_I]
Indonesian
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all the lazy properties of an entity class belongs to a group named DEFAULT. And fetching any property of the DEFAULT group fetches others as well. To solve this problem, we need to define groups that we wish to fetch individually using the `@LazyGroup` annotation.

So, we are annotating both nationality and maritalStatus with @LazyGroup annotation as below.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
@LazyGroup("nationality")
@JoinColumn(name="nationality", referencedColumnName="code", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Nationality nationality;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
@LazyGroup("maritalStatus")
@JoinColumn(name="marital_status", referencedColumnName="code", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private MaritalStatus maritalStatus;
```

And hopefully, you are using Bytecode Enhancement for No-proxy lazy fetching

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. I never knew this before :D. I'll try it out in my code now. And Yes! I'm using Bytecode Enhancement as I found this is the only way to make this work, at least for to-one relationships... Please correct me if this statement is wrong though :)

Comment: Its a long story when what to use :)

Comment: @Mr.J4mes You can get additional information from hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-lazy-loading)

Comment: @SternK I do google and skim through documentations from time to time but it's a huge document. At times, I find it hard to find the exact details I need to solve a problem such as this one :D. Sometimes, asking people with experience does help.